# How to toggle svg icons on button click - Using QT C++

Tags: qt, svg

I am relatively new to svg + QT concepts.
I have created an svg icon which has 2 states.
I want to add this svg icon to a QPushButton. When the button is clicked,the icon should get toggled ( show the other state ).

Can anybody pls give me a heads up on how to do this in QT? QT with C++!

Edit:

I have tried using the svg icon and toggling it when button is clicked.
I have achieved the expected behavior but I wonder if this is the correct way of doing it.

I am pasting the code files and the svg icon content below

---

I have tried something using the QSvgRenderer and QIcon.
I have achieved what I was looking for.

But I am not sure if this is how it should be done.
Please have a look and let me know if this is the preferred way or not.

I have created a svg icon ( using 2 other svg icons ) from the https://nucleoapp.com/tool/icon-transition
The svg icon has 2 svg icons embedded into it. My objective now is to toggle the icons when button is clicked.

Checkout my files below

```
    #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSvgRenderer>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    bool isDefaultIconLoaded;
    QString otherIconSvgContent;
    QString defaultIconSvgContent;

    QSvgRenderer m_svgRenderer;

    void loadCurrentSvgIcon(QByteArray ba);

private slots:
    void toolBtnClicked();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

The cpp file

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QtSvg/QSvgRenderer>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QDomDocument>
#include <QDomNodeList>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    isDefaultIconLoaded(true)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);;
    connect(ui->toolButton, &QToolButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::toolBtnClicked);
    ui->toolButton->setStyleSheet("border:none;");

    // open svg icon which has multiple states
    QFile file(":/icon/theSvg.svg");
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    const QByteArray baData = file.readAll();
    QDomDocument doc;
    doc.setContent(baData, false);

    // Read both the <g> elements from the .svg xml and store each 'icon content' in member var.
    QDomNodeList gList = doc.elementsByTagName("g");
    for(int i = 0; i < gList.size(); i++)
    {
        QString aContent;
        QTextStream ts(&aContent);
        gList.at(i).save(ts,0);
        qDebug("%s", qPrintable(aContent));

        if( isDefaultIconLoaded )
        {
            defaultIconSvgContent.insert(0, "<svg>");
            defaultIconSvgContent += aContent;;
            defaultIconSvgContent.append("</svg>");
            isDefaultIconLoaded = false;
            qDebug() <<defaultIconSvgContent;
        }
        else {
            otherIconSvgContent.insert(0, "<svg>");
            otherIconSvgContent += aContent;
            otherIconSvgContent.append("</svg>");
            qDebug() <<otherIconSvgContent;
        }
    }

    // Load the default svg icon first
   QByteArray ba = defaultIconSvgContent.toUtf8();
   isDefaultIconLoaded = true;
   loadCurrentSvgIcon(ba);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::loadCurrentSvgIcon(QByteArray ba)
{
   m_svgRenderer.load(ba);
   QPixmap pix(m_svgRenderer.defaultSize());
    QPainter pixPainter(&pix);
    m_svgRenderer.render(&pixPainter);
    QIcon myicon(pix);

    ui->toolButton->setIcon(myicon);
}

void MainWindow::toolBtnClicked()
{
    if ( isDefaultIconLoaded == true )
    {
        // Toggle the icon to "other"
        QByteArray ba = otherIconSvgContent.toUtf8();
        loadCurrentSvgIcon(ba);
        isDefaultIconLoaded = false;
    }
    else {
        QByteArray ba = defaultIconSvgContent.toUtf8();
        loadCurrentSvgIcon(ba);
        isDefaultIconLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

Content of the svg file

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" height="16" width="16">
    <g 
      class="nc-icon-wrapper" stroke-width="1" fill="#111111" stroke="#111111">
      <title>default</title>
    <path 
      fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" data-color="color-2" d="M1.5 1.5h2">      
    </path>
    <circle 
      fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="9" cy="9" r="3.5" data-color="color-2">
    </circle>
      <path 
        fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" data-color="color-2" d="M2.5 5.5h1">        
      </path>
      <path 
        fill="none" stroke="#111111" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M14.5 3.5h-2l-1-2h-5l-1 2h-4a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v9a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h13a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-9a1 1 0 0 0-1-1z">
      </path>
  </g>
    <g 
      class="nc-icon-wrapper" fill="#111111">
      <title>other</title>
    <path 
      fill="#111111" d="M15,3h-2.5l-1.7-2.6C10.6,0.2,10.3,0,10,0H6C5.7,0,5.4,0.2,5.2,0.4L3.5,3H1C0.4,3,0,3.4,0,4v11 c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h14c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1V4C16,3.4,15.6,3,15,3z M14,14H2V5h2c0.3,0,0.6-0.2,0.8-0.4L6.5,2h2.9l1.7,2.6 C11.4,4.8,11.7,5,12,5h2V14z">
    </path> 
    <circle 
      data-color="color-2" cx="8" cy="9" r="3">      
    </circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

basically, each 'g' element represents an icon.
I am reading the each g element contents in C'tor and storing them into member variables ( in order to avoid reading again and again ).

Then I am "loading" the icon based on the click event using the "QSvgRenderer".

This works as expected, but is it the best practice or is there a better way I can acheive this ?

Comment: share your .svg

Comment: I have added the svg image contents. Please have a look.

Note: I can use the svg icon as any normal png icon. For example doing pushButton->setIcon(QIcon(QStringLiteral(":/images/icon.svg"))) Will work correctly ( the icon will be used for push button). But Toggling is the one I would like to acheive.

Comment: FYI: I had created my svg icon using https://nucleoapp.com/tool/icon-transition